# Setting the default vaue of an instance-specific variable via a class-specific variable

Tags: python

Which one is better from the efficiency point of view?

```
class Foo(object):
    rarelyChanged = 1

    def makeRareChange(self, newValue):
        self.rarelyChanged = newValue
```

vs

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.rarelyChanged = 1

    def makeRareChange(self, newValue):
        self.rarelyChanged = newValue
```

The idea is that `rarelyChanged` can be an instance-specific variable which uses a class-specific fallback value. This is something frequently done in JavaScript (i.e. assigning the default value of a variable to `prototype` rather than in constructor) - is there the same pattern in Python?

Comment: Do you mean by class-specific value a value which is for every instance the same?

Comment: The first version will save memory.  The second may be slightly faster because the name belongs to the object rather than the class and can therefore be resolved more quickly.  Or it may be slightly slower because assignment needs to occur every time an object is created.

Comment: yeah - that "fall-back" behaviour is actually quite confusing. I mean for sake of clarity chose option #2
(I know that this is an old question)